# Symfony ChoiceType with big array, error 'This value is not valid.'

Tags: arrays, symfony

I have a form with a ChoiceType. Values are set with a Ajax request (this choice depends of an other choice).

But there is many choices (13200), And when I submit the the form whith a correct choice, I have this error "This value is not valid.".

I have tried whith 100 choices, and it's work well.

This form is build whith EventsListener (simplified version) :

```
 $ff = $builder->getFormFactory();
    // function to add 'template' choice field dynamically
    $func = function ( \Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $e) use ($ff, $curlRequest, $builder, $rapport) {
        $data = $e->getData();
        $form = $e->getForm();

        if ($form->has('idsSouscripteur') )
        {
            $form->remove('idsSouscripteur');
        }

        $idClient = $data->getIdClient() > 0 ? $data->getIdClient() : null;
        $idsSouscripteur = count($data->getIdsSouscripteur()) > 0 ? $data->getIdsSouscripteur() : null;

        $souscripteursArray = [];
        if (!is_null($idClient)) {
            $souscripteurs = /* Request to get 'souscripteurs' objects */;

            foreach ($souscripteurs as $souscripteur) {
                $souscripteursArray[$souscripteur->nomSouscripteur] = $souscripteur->numInterne;
            }
        }

        $form
            ->add('idsSouscripteur', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'rapports.block_2.souscripteur',
                'mapped' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices' => $souscripteursArray,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank()
                ),
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'rapports.block_2.souscripteur_placeholder'
                ]
            ]);

        if (!is_null($idsSouscripteur)) {
            $rapport->setIdsSouscripteur($idsSouscripteur);
        }
    };

    // Register the function above as EventListener on PreSet and PreBind
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $func);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $func);
```

Anyone lnow why symfony is not working with big array ?

Comment: how does SelectModalType::class look like ? It is a custom FormType right ?

Comment: Sorry :). Yes it's a custom ChoiceType. I will try a basic ChoiceType to eliminate this possibile error.

Comment: I have test the form type to ChoiceType and I have the same error